# How can I prevent someone from zooming in to a photograph I send them?

Tags: photoshop, digital, resolution, file-format

I have a photograph named `A.jpg`. I have to send it to some other person and I dont want him to zoom it more than 30%.
Is there any such option? I am ready to change my extension of the photograph also, to e.g. `A.pdf` or something.

Comment: I'm sorry but the question is not possible to answer. Zooming into a photograph isn't well defined unless you state at what PPI you're viewing it. What you can do is to lower the resolution of the photo. That will limit the detail. Unfortunately I don't think that this question belongs to Photo.SE, since it's not really related to photography.

Comment: This makes no sense at all. If you sent an image to someone viewing on a phone vs a 4K display, it would take completely different resolutions to zoom at 30%. The only thing you can do is send an image with the maximum details you want them to see.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't possible, because computers do not work like this. Once someone has the data, they can generally do whatever they want with it. Now, it is certainly the case that big media companies would like to cripple computers so this isn't true, by introducing DRM — "digital rights management", where the "rights" are really "restrictions". This is used for streaming movies and music, and sometimes games. You could theoretically send your photo using some program which includes this kind of software, but generally it is a) expensive, b) difficult to use, and c) not actually very effective. And that would even presume something exists tailored to your photo display task — and I don't think it does.

So, in that case, the answer here is simply to not send the full-resolution photo to the other person. Simply use Photoshop or some other software to rescale the image to be much smaller. I don't know exactly what you mean by "zoom it more than 30%", but basically, the strategy would be to make it so that zooming in all the way to 1:1 would only show the level of detail you want.

Comment: if OP wants to hide faces or car numbers, one can downsample to decrease resolution so that everything visible in zooms more than 100% will be blurred out.

Answer (score 1):

There is no common file format, that is able to prevent zooming. Your only option is to decrease the resolution so far, that the details you don't want to show get lost.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible.  The most basic way to 'zoom' in on a picture is to display it on a huge screen, like a TV.  That will already zoom the picture several times larger, and you cannot stop that.